# wildfly docker image authentication issue

Tags: jboss, docker, wildfly, dockerfile

I've followed the instructions on the following link: [WildFly Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jboss/wildfly/) in the section **Extending the image**

However, after I make the build, when I go to the URL http://localhost:9990, I have the following message:

```
The management interface could not be loaded.

Authentication required.
```

Comment: I don't think you can access it via local host. You need to get the IP address of your docker container.

Comment: get into your container with `docker exec -it container bash` and debug, with `netstat -an` or `lsof -i:9000` (maybe you will need to install lsof or such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [James R. Perkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152794/james-r-perkins) noted in his comment, I can't access it with localhost, I used docker host IP address and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to map Wildfly management port and allow remote connections to the management interface:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 -it jboss/wildfly -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
```

This will allow access to the console via http://localhost:9990/console/App.html or http://127.0.0.1:9990/console/index.html (in case of Keycloak images)

Source: https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly